How to upload files to "github.com/<owner>/<repo>/files/<number>/<file_name>"?
I don't know how the file (https://github.com/Flexget/Flexget/files/13787215/pendulum-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.zip) is uploaded, and I saw someone uploaded the file here.
I only know how to upload files to repositories, but I don't know how to upload files to github.com/<owner>/<repo>/files/<number>/<file_name>.
Is there a page on GitHub to upload files to github.com/<owner>/<repo>/files/<number>/<file_name>?

This is no longer possible after it was exposed as a viable attack vector for distributing malicious file attachments like malware, even if you weren't the owner of that repository. The sources linked below cover the vulnerability in further detail.
Formerly, you were able to upload these files by attaching them to issues or issue comments using the Paste, drop, or click to add files button below the rich text editor.
All user attachment uploads will now have URLs in the following format, clearing distancing them from the repo to which they were uploaded:
https://github.com/user-attachments/files/FILE_ID/FILE_NAME.EXT

It is my understanding the files uploaded prior to this change support both the former and new URL formats.
News Sources:

Brodie Robertson's YouTube Summary
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/github-comments-abused-to-push-malware-via-microsoft-repo-urls/
https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/other-blogs/mcafee-labs/redline-stealer-a-novel-approach/
https://research.openanalysis.net/github/lua/2024/03/03/lua-malware.html

